# Кросс-компиляция из ubuntu 11.04 x32 под windows7 x64

Tags: кросс-компиляция, mingw, windows-7, c++, linux

Мне необходимо собрать один проект на C++ под Windows 7 x64, как сказано в README файле:

```
Compiling under Linux:
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Cross-Compiling under Linux, for Windows

```
$ ./configure  --host=i586-pc-mingw32
$ make
```

я установил MinGW под ubuntu (11.04, x32):
sudo apt-get install mingw32

но и скомпилил всё:

```
> $ CC=i586-mingw32msvc-g++ ./configure --host=i586-pc-mingw32 && make
```

Всё нормально собралось, но только под windows 7 не работает. Выдаёт ошибку: [image]
А под winXP нормально работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите mingw64

```
[http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/latest/download][1]

./configure
 make
 sudo make install
Предварительно в менеджере пакетов Synaptic найдите все пакеты mingw и отметьте их для удаления. Далее или по схеме предложенной выше или поставьте в Synaptic галочку на пакете mingw-w64 и установите его
```

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install mingw64
[sudo] password for igor: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mingw64`

Comment: как правильно установить mingw64 ?

Comment: Лучше через Synaptic. Сначала нужно удалить версию 32, потом уже ставить 64. Почему-то вместе не уживаются.

Comment: Ну да, как в анекдоте про грузина, продававшего порошок от тараканов - Можно и так как ви говорите! :) Спасибо за коммент

Comment: Можно как Вы предлагаете - из сырцов. Долго и мучительно и не факт, что получится. А можно культурно из репозитория.

Comment: Исправил. Мы не ищем легких путей :)

Comment: Это потому что Вы еще молодой и имеете до хрена свободного времени

Comment: Хм. Молодость, по-вашему, это до какого возраста? И какого именно - биологического или программерского? :)

Comment: Предлагаю закрыть тему.